# Android can't retrieve data from web service using session ID

Tags: android, web-services, session, sessionid

I'm a beginner of android programming. I had started a test project which is about using an android app to access web service and run function there. I am using ksoap2 to call the web services.

When I want to login to a database through phone and the web service return a session ID to me. But after that, When I want to run other function in service, and I pass it in session ID, it tell me that there is a null object reference. I tried use the session ID again to get back the login details but it shows that the session doesn't point to any session. This is the method which allow me to connect with web services. While for android, I just simply call using ksoap2.

```
 <WebMethod(True)> _
Public Function CompanyConnectionString() As String

    Dim lErrCode, lRetCode As Long
    Dim sErrMsg As String = ""


    Dim sSessionID As String = ""
    Dim oCompany As SAPbobsCOM.Company
    oCompany = New SAPbobsCOM.Company


//  User and other details to connect
    oCompany.Server = "xx.x.x.xx"    //ip address
    oCompany.DbServerType = SAPbobsCOM.BoDataServerTypes.dst_MSSQL2012
    oCompany.DbUserName = "dbUser"
    oCompany.DbPassword = "dbPassword"
    oCompany.CompanyDB = "CompanyDB"
    oCompany.UserName = "User"
    oCompany.Password = "Password"
    oCompany.LicenseServer = "xx.x.x.xx:xxxxx"  // ip


    lRetCode = oCompany.Connect


    If lRetCode <> 0 Then
        oCompany.GetLastError(lErrCode, sErrMsg)
        sSessionID = lErrCode & "-" & sErrMsg

    Else
        sSessionID = Session.SessionID.ToString
        Session.Add(sSessionID, oCompany)
        ''
        Cookies.SetCookies(oCompany, "SID")


    End If

    Return sSessionID

End Function
```

I found that it might lose the session ID and I can't get back the login details for other functions later. So is that any idea for that? How I gonna do? without this I can't proceed further in my program.

Thank in advance..

Comment: what are you using on server side?? simple servlet  or mvc???

Comment: @Dev my webservice is using .Net in asmx format

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem had just solved. Me and my friend found out that that is because the sessionID is forgotten due to the `max-age=0;`. So we add that to our sessionID and it ran.

```
if (headerKey != null) {
    if (headerKey.equals("Set-Cookie")) {
        cookieBuilder.append(headerValue + "max-age=86400;");
    }
} //headervalue is the sessionID
```

This will allow the session to stay active for 86400 seconds = 1 day.
So the sessionID can be use for running other function on web service